# how to zip folder and its content using zlib under cocoa framework

Tags: zlib

How can i zipped folder and its content using zlib 1.2.3 under cocoa framework. It seems

that zlib is used for only zipping files and not folder(with reference from other mailing

list), else is there any possibility to do so in cocoa application.

Thanks and Regards,
iSight